# How to perform different tasks based on server Message on android app?

Tags: java, android, tcp

I created working chat application in android and java based server using TCP/Ip . But now i want to perform tasks like vibration in phone when server send particular string such as   "Vibrate" ... I tried if servermsg="Vibrate" (And called another class) but not working...
 Help Pls....

Answer (score 0):

i would start off by testing your logic to see where the issue is occuring.

for starters, you should print your server message to the console to see what is actually coming back. odds are that it's also wrapped in some kind of json object, so you'll probably need to parse the response also. if you can print the server response and then post it here we can have a read and help you resolve this.

Comment: I used This one. http://prashantandroid.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-client-connected-with-socket.html....  And You will see the line at TCPclient.java class. where we can put the condition for each server message..